# Summation of series involving binomial coefficients : $\sum_{r=1}^n {n\choose r}r^{n-r}$.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I was trying to find the sum of the following series: $\sum_{r=1}^n {n\choose r}r^{n-r}.$

Actually, this series came out as the answer to the question : Find the number of functions $f(n)$ on set $A,$ where $A = \{1,2,...,n\},$ such that $f(f(n)) = f(n)$ for all $n \in A. $

I wondered whether I could give the answer to the question as a closed form expression, but I have no idea how to convert the series into a closed form expression.
Does this series even have a closed form expression?
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you mean the series $$\sum_{r=1}^n\binom nr r^{n-r}\;?$$

Comment: Yes. I meant that.

Comment: @NoChance That doesn't fit the binomial theorem...

Comment: Is there a reason to expect a closed formula? A lot of inclusion-exclusion examples give sums like this, and I've never seen a closed formula.

Comment: @DonAntonio, and Thomas Andrews, thanks for the catch!

Comment: I'm not sure if the existence of a closed formula can be expected. I was just curious! It's so similar looking to the standard binomial theorem, but yet it is so different!

Comment: [`A000248`](https://oeis.org/A000248) @OEIS